# How do I convert a sum (from $1$ to $n$) of powers into a function of $n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

This question is going to need some context. The TL;DR is:

How do I get a function equal to $\sum_{i=1}^n1.15^i$ without using sums?

---

I'm using Google sheets to keep track of something and as far as I know it doesn't support sequences or sums in one line (I don't want to have every terms of sequence in one cell and then sum the cells). Though *this isn't a question about how to do things in Google sheets*. Last time I had a sequence I managed to find a function using simple factors with Wolfram Alpha, equal to the sequence.

The first sequence is :

> $A_n = A_{n-1}\times1.15$
>
> $A_0 = a $

$A_0$ is variable and goes in a cell. For this sequence, I use $A_n = A_0\times1.15^n$, or as a function $f_a(n)=a\times1.15^n$.

The second sequence $B$ is the sum of all the terms of $A$.

> $B_n = \sum_{i=1}^n A_i $
>
> $ B_n = \sum_{i=1}^n A_0\times1.15^i$
>
> $ B_n = A_0 \sum_{i=1}^n 1.15^i$

And that is problematic to calculate with a "google sheets friendly" function. For example, $B_3$ goes like this:

> $B_3 = A_3 + A_2 + A_1 + A_0$
>
> $B_3 = a\times1.15^3 + a\times1.15^2 + a\times1.15 + a$
>
> $B_3 = a (1.15^3 + 1.15^2 + 1.15 + 1)$

So I have get this series of polynonial-looking terms and I have no idea how I can write a function that calculates $B_3$ and $B_n$ easily, without having to use a cell for each term. I've reduced my problem to calculating the sum I gave in the TL;DR but I'm stuck there.

If it's unclear what I'm asking, I just want to know if there's an **easy way** to calculate $\sum_{i=1}^n1.15^i$ for a given $n$ without using sums (i.e. without having to calculate each term of the sum). "No" is an acceptable answer, and any other way to express the same thing is welcome.

Also, is there a name for the act of finding an expression of $U_n$ that uses only $U_0$ instead of $U_{n-1}$?

Comment: This is a standard [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) and closed formulas are known (see the link).

Comment: @lulu post the geometric series sum as an answer for the newbie who's not studying math?

Comment: @lulu Thanks, but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. There's only a small bit about Geometric power series, and I don't want a formula to infinity, I want something that works for a specific $n$.

Comment: Who uses comma to denote the decimal separator?

Comment: @tst A number of languages, like French or German for example (see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html). But this site is in English I should have used a dot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula you want is $$\sum_{i=0}^n x^i = \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}.$$

This can be seen as follows:

\begin{align*}
(1-x)(1 + x + \cdots + x^n) &= (1 + x + \dots + x^n) - x(1 + x + \dots + x^n)\\
&=(1 + x + \dots + x^n) - (x + x^2 + \dots + x^{n+1})\\
&= 1 - x^{n+1}.
\end{align*}

Then plug in your $x = 1.15$ (and subtract $1$ since you begin with the index $i=1$ instead of $i=0$).

Comment: Thanks, this *is* the formula I want! Does it have a name? (The form on the right I mean)

Comment: I don't know if there's a name for this formula.  You could call the partial sum of a geometric series, a geometric sum, or somesuch.

Comment: Thanks, "partial sum" is what I was looking for :)